# Resolving Predefined Agent Variables in Runtime Expressions

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-services

I have the following scenario, it is simplified for the sake of brevity, but outlines my problem.

I have a 2 Job pipeline.

`BreakMatrix` Job: A job that runs on an `AdminPool` and outputs 2 variables with the following names `ENV1` and `ENV2`. The names are **important** because each of them matches the name of an Environment running in a separate `MachinePool` VM deployment pool.

`Upgrade` Job: A deployment job that depends on the `BreakMatrix` job and that runs on a VM *MachinePool*, with a tag that will select `ENV1` and `ENV2` environments.

I am trying to pass in one of the variables to each of the corresponding Environments:

```yaml
    - job: BreakMatrix
      pool: AdminPool
      steps:
      - checkout: none
      - powershell: |
          $result1 = @{"Hostname" = "Env1Value"}
          $result2 = @{"Hostname" = "Env2Value"}
          Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ENV1;isOutput=true;]$result1"
          Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ENV2;isOutput=true;]$result2"
        name: outputter

    - deployment: Upgrade
      dependsOn: BreakMatrix
      variables:
        agentName: $(Environment.ResourceName)
        agentName2: $(Agent.Name)
        formatted: $[ format('outputter.{0}', variables['agentName']) ]
        result1: $[ dependencies.BreakMatrix.outputs[format('outputter.{0}', variables['agentName'])] ]
        result2: $[ dependencies.BreakMatrix.outputs[format('outputter.{0}', variables['agentName2'])] ]
        result3: $[ dependencies.BreakMatrix.outputs[format('outputter.{0}', variables['Agent.Name'])] ]
        hardcode: $[ dependencies.BreakMatrix.outputs['outputter.ENV2'] ]
        json: $[ convertToJson(dependencies.BreakMatrix.outputs) ]
      environment:
        name: MachinePool
        resourceType: VirtualMachine
        tags: deploy-dynamic
      strategy:
        rolling:
          preDeploy:
            steps:
              - powershell: |
                  echo 'Predeploy'
                  echo "agentName: $(agentName)"
                  echo "agentName2: $(agentName2)"
                  echo "env: $(Environment.ResourceName)"
                  echo "formatted: $(formatted)"
                  echo "harcode: $(harcode)"
                  echo "result1: $(result1)"
                  echo "result2: $(result2)"
                  echo "result3: $(result3)"
                  echo "json: $(json)"
          deploy:
            steps:
              - powershell: |
                  echo 'Deploy'
```

Output for `ENV2` pre-deploy step:

```
Predeploy
agentName: ENV2
agentName2: ENV2
env: ENV2
formatted: outputter.ENV2
hardcode: {
Hostname:Env2Value}
result1: 
result2: 
result3: 
json: {
  
outputter.ENV2: 
\"Hostname\":\"Env2Value\"

}
```

If i try to use a [predefined variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#agent-variables-devops-services) in a [dependency expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#use-outputs-in-a-different-job) they don't seem to properly resolve, but if i just simply map them to a variable / format them they work.
Note: The environment names are actually dynamically calculated before these jobs run so I cannot use parameters or static/compile time variables.

Any suggestions on how to pass in only the relevant variable to each of the environments ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got confirmation on the [developer community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/use-predefined-deployment-variable-to-resolve-vari/1560494?from=email&viewtype=all#T-ND1562237) that this is not possible.

Relevant part:

> But I am afraid that the requirement couldn’t be achieved.
>
> The reason is that the dependencies.xx.outputs expression can’t read
> the variable(variables['Agent.Name']) and format expression value
> defined in the YAML pipeline.
>
> It now only supports hard-coding the name of the variable to get the
> corresponding job variable value.